# JavaFX - Launching an application with an object parameter from a different class

Tags: java, javafx

I'm in the process of using JavaFX to create a GUI which interacts with a ServerInterface class. The JavaFX class is called ServerWindow and will be launched by another class called Launcher which I can edit but I must use it. I'm trying to attach a ServerInterface object to the ServerWindow, but however I try it, I get errors.
First, I tried passing it as a parameter but JavaFX does not like parameters other than String args being passed through it when Application.launch(...) is called.
Next, I tried this:

```
ServerWindow s = new ServerWindow();
s.addServer(new MockServer());
s.launch(s.getClass(), "");
```

This seems to call the ServerWindow class twice, and the second time is the one that has the Server Attached. Is there anyway to get the program to launch while passing it a parameter?

Edit - Adding Examples:

```
class GUI extends Application{
    private ServerInstance server;
    public GUI(ServerInstance s){ 
        this.server = s
    }
    public static void Start(){
        System.out.println(this.server.getServerName());
    }

}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DummyServer ds = new DummyServer(); //Implements ServerInterface
        Application.launch(GUI.class, ds)

    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot construct your Application object directly;  JavaFX must do it.  You can, however, pass parameters for configuration.  For example:  `Application.launch(ServerWindow.class, "--mock=true");`

Comment: @VGR This is useful but in the future this could have any class attached to it as a server as long as it implements the correct interface - would there be a way to allow for this without hardcoding the different types in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the class name:

```
Application.launch(GUI.class, DummyServer.class.getName());
```

Then in your application, you can create the object:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage)
throws ReflectiveOperationException {

    String serverClassName = getParameters().getRaw().get(0);

    Class<? extends ServerInstance> serverClass =
        Class.forName(serverClassName).asSubclass(ServerInstance.class);

    this.server = serverClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works! Just for future reference, in the line
'Class<? extends ServerInstance> serverClass =
        Class.forName(serverClassName).asSubclass(ServerInstance.class);', is the 'Class<? extends ServerInstance>' used to create a generic class of unknown type which is accepted as long as it extends the ServerInstance?

Comment: Yes, [asSubclass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) is guaranteed to return a generically typesafe reference to the Class object (or throw an exception if that isn’t possible).